# How to prevent the function passed to Optional's orElse from being executed when the Optional is not empty?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

If I'm calling a function from `orElse`, the function is executed even if the `Optional` is not empty. Is there any way to restrict the execution of the function to only when the `Optional` is empty?

```
Optional.ofNullable(someValue).orElse(someFunction());
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`someFunction()` gets executed since it's an argument passed to a method, and the arguments passed to a method are evaluated before the method is executed. To avoid the execution, you should pass `someFunction()` within a `Supplier` instance.

Use [`orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-) instead of `orElse` :

```
Optional.ofNullable(someValue).orElseGet(SomeClass::someFunction);
```

or

```
Optional.ofNullable(someValue).orElseGet(()->someFunction());
```

Comment: Using a no argument function to delay a computation like is is sometimes called a 'thunk'.